# Three persons entering a railway carriage where there are 5 vacant seats. In how many ways can they seat themselves?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In the question, three persons entering a railway carriage where there are $5$ vacant
seats. In how many ways can they seat themselves?

Why are we multiplying $5\times 4\times 3$? Ive read the fundamental principle of counting but still I cant apply much of it in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose one person: they have 5 places in which they can sit.

Choose the second person: they have 4 places. Likewise, the third person has three places.

Thus, $5 \times 4 \times 3$ possible arrangements.

Comment: yeah but why are we multiplying them?

Comment: Drawing a tree diagram might help you understand why. The first person would have five branches going from them - one per possible seat. The second person (at the end of each of those five branches) would have four further branches. And then at the end of each of those, the third person has three further branches. The number of endpoints would correspond to the number of seating arrangements - it should be clear that there are $5 \times 4 \times 3$ endpoints when you think of it like that.

Comment: can you draw and explain??

Comment: Yes!!! i got it thanks!